# How to call a function on click of a button from controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i want to call handleUploadFinished function on click on submit button from controller

```
else if(requestType == 'EIV Household Report') {
        var buttons ='[{"label": "Submit","variant":"Neutral","name": "Submit","value": "Submit","align":"center"}]';
        component.find('confirmationDialogBox').set("v.buttons",buttons);//How to call a function on we click on this submit button 
        component.find('confirmationDialogBox').toggleDialogBox();
        component.set("v.caseRecord",fields);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `handleUploadFinished` method in helper.js and then you can call from controller.js like this

```
onSumbit: function(component, evt, helper) {
      helper.handleUploadFinished (component, evt);
}
```